# Jquery Dropdownlist Select Change

Tags: jquery

RED
     BLACK
     BLUE
     WHITE
     PINK

i not to want $('#COLOR').val(2);

i want $('#COLOR').val('RED');

How to make ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select by value, pass that into the [`.val(newValue)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) call, like this:

```
$('#COLOR').val('0');
```

This will select "RED" because it has `value="0"` for it's `<option>` element.

---

For the updated question: to select by *text* there are a few approaches, for example:

```
$("#COLOR").val(function() {
  return $('option', this).filter(function() { 
    return this.innerHTML == 'RED'; 
  }).attr('value');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HsnAW/2/).
​

Comment: @oraclee - I added how to do this to the answer, this works in the case of `<outgroup>` elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the value "RED", which will allow you to do what you want?  Or do you have to keep the same HTML.  For example

```
<option value="RED">RED</option>
```